# Problem in using \everymath{\sansmath}

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I would like to use `\everymath{\sansmath}` and change the typeset of all the equations in my document as a replacement for using `\sansmath{$equation$}`. However, I am not what I am missing that declaring `\everymath{\sansmath}` does not cause anything to change.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}

\begin{document}


\everymath{\sansmath} 

\verb|\everymath{\sansmath}| gives $E=mc^2$

\verb|\sansmath{$E=mc^2$}  | gives \sansmath{$E=mc^2$}


\end{document}
```

The result is illustrated below.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To make every math in sans, just issue `\sansmath` at the beginning of the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath               %% <<--- this
\begin{document}

\verb|\everymath{\sansmath}| gives $E=mc^2$

\verb|\sansmath{$E=mc^2$}  | gives \sansmath{$E=mc^2$} 

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you want to limit the sans to certain part, you may either put the command inside a group, or use the environment form `\begin{sansmath}....\end{sansmath}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath
\begin{document}

\verb|\sansmath| gives $E=mc^2$

\unsansmath
\verb|\unsansmath| gives $E=mc^2$

{
\sansmath
With grouping, gives $E=mc^2$
}
After group we get $E=mc^2$

Within environment \verb|sansmath| gives 

\begin{sansmath}
$E=mc^2$
\end{sansmath}

\sansmath 
Again,
\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\unsansmath` was a nice command that I should remember.