# How to typeset math in sansserif in figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, sans-serif

I am trying to typeset math in sansserif font in tikz figures and I have followed some of the guidance I found here, but I am not getting the results. I am including a MWE and would very much appreciate some help in getting it right.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\input{../bookdef}
\input{../tikz-include}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}},>=triangle 45}
\usepackage{float} % to easily modify floats
\usepackage{sansmath} % sans serif math
\usepackage{everyhook} % nice \every... patching
% restyle figures to make \everymath=\sansmath (float package)
\restylefloat{figure}
\floatevery{figure}{\PushPreHook{math}{\sansmath}}
% undo the change to \everymath at the end of the figure (etoolbox)
\apptocmd{\endfigure}{\PopPreHook{math}}{}{}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzexternalize[prefix=./Chapter11]

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
circ/.style={circle,draw,minimum width=0.7cm, minimum height=0.7cm},
box/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum width=1cm, rounded corners},
font={\fontsize{10pt}{12}\selectfont}
}

\node[minimum size=2cm,regular polygon,draw,regular polygon sides=3,shape border rotate=-90,text width=0.5cm,inner sep=-2mm,outer sep=-0pt] (a) {\hspace{-6pt}\parbox{0.5cm}{Data\\[-4pt]Source}};
\node[circ,right= of a] (p2) {P};
\node[box, above right= of p2,yshift=-1cm] (w4) {$W_{4}$};
\node[box, below right= of p2,yshift=1cm] (w5) {$W_{5}$};
\node[fit=(p2)(w4) (w5), draw, dashed, inner sep=0.3cm] {};
\node[above=7pt of p2,xshift=8pt] (lbl1) {Operation 2};
\draw[->] (a) -- (p2);
\draw[->] (p2) -- (w4);
\draw[->] (p2) -- (w5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are loading `\input{../bookdef}
\input{../tikz-include}`, which probably nobody has. (You probably need `\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.geometric,positioning,fit,external}`.)  And then: how important is `externalize` for that question? Why are you loading pgfplots? Finally, what is the question, i.e. what do you want to achieve? Did you try `font=\sffamily` in the nodes?

Comment: @marmot +1 for your comment, -1 for the question.

Comment: Sorry my mistake -- shouldn't cut-and-paste in the middle of the night. I can clean it up, but let me read the other comments first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on question [problem-in-using-everymath-sansmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196299/problem-in-using-everymath-sansmath) after reducing your mwe to

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit,positioning,,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{sansmath} % sans serif math
\sansmath % if you use it globaly


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance =1mm and 12mm,
circ/.style = {circle, draw, minimum width=0.7cm, minimum height=0.7cm},
 box/.style = {rectangle, draw, minimum width=1cm, rounded corners},
font =\sffamily% \sansmath % if you use it only in this picture

                        ]
\node[regular polygon,draw, regular polygon sides=3, shape border rotate=-90,
      minimum size=2cm, text width=1cm, inner sep=-1mm, outer sep=0pt] (a) {Data\\[-2pt]Source};
\node[circ,right= of a] (p2) {P};
\node[box, above right=of p2] (w4) {$W_{4}$};
\node[box, below right=of p2] (w5) {$W_{5}$};
\node[fit=(p2)(w4) (w5), draw, dashed,inner sep=3mm, xshift=-2mm] (FIT) {};
\node[below right] (lbl1) at (FIT.north west) {Operation 2};
\draw[->] (a) -- (p2);
\draw[->] (p2) -- (w4);
\draw[->] (p2) -- (w5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you will obtain:

[image]