# Unitalicized capital Greek with sansmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, etoolbox, sans-serif, helvetica, sansmathfonts

In my PhD thesis, the main text is in Times, and all of my figures (and their captions) are set in Helvetica. I've created the following MWE that shows how I can can toggle between Times and Helvetica between the main text and the figures. My current issue is that I don't have an automatic way to globally set all of the capital Greek letters to be unitalicized. All other math symbols (lower case, and upper case roman) should be italicized. This is the convention in my field.

The only work-around that I have right now is to put a \mathrm before every occurence of capital Greek letters in my document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{tgheros,textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{sansmath} % sans serif math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font={small,sf}]{caption}

% Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444408/61268
\usepackage{etoolbox} % nice command patching
\usepackage{everyhook} % nice \every... patching
% restyle figures to make \everymath=\sansmath (float package)
\restylefloat{figure}
\floatevery{figure}{\PushPreHook{math}{\sansmath}}
% undo the change to \everymath at the end of the figure (etoolbox)
\apptocmd{\endfigure}{\PopPreHook{math}}{}{}

\tikzset{font=\sffamily\small}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

Main text is in Times. Works without a problem.

\begin{equation}
    \Delta\Omega(t)
\end{equation}

My problem is in the figures, which I usually typeset using Ti\emph{k}z

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0, 0) {Helvetica Equation: $\Delta\Omega(t)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Captions are in Helvetica. $\Delta\Omega(t)$}
\end{figure}

I found that I can get a fix if I manually put a {\textbackslash}mathrm around all of my capital Greek letters, but I would like to find a way for this to automatically be done.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0, 0) {{\textbackslash}mathrm: $\mathrm{\Delta\Omega}(t)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{I can fix with {\textbackslash}mathrm... $\mathrm{\Delta\Omega}(t)$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of MWE]

Comment: Are you averse to using `\usepackage[EULERGREEK]{sansmath}` ?— it completely changes the font used for Greek, but the uppercase variants are upright. An alternative would be to do a bunch of redefinitions like `\let\oldDelta\Delta \renewcommand{\Delta}{\mathrm{\oldDelta}}` which you'd only have to do in the preamble.

Comment: Using the `\let\oldDelta\Delta \renewcommand{\Delta}{\mathrm{\oldDelta}}` seems to be the preferred solution so far, since it preserves my Helvetica font.

Comment: Not related but I find that using Ti*k*Z for those simple frames is a bit of a sledgehammer.

Comment: @SebGlav indeed it is. In my thesis, I'm drawing more complicated diagrams. I'm just posting a MWE.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can do this with `unicode-math`.

However, the command to force upright sans-serif Greek will be `\symsfup`, not `\mathrm`.

Alternatively, instead of `\Delta\Omega`, type `\increment\mupOmega`.  This will allow you to use the upright Greek letters from your `\mathrm` font for `version=sans`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, font={small,sf}]{caption}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{KPMath-Sans.otf}[version=sans]
\setmathfontface\mathrm{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfontface\mathrm{TeX Gyre Heros}[version=sans]

\newcommand\sansmath{\mathversion{sans}}

% Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444408/61268
\usepackage{etoolbox} % nice command patching
 \usepackage{everyhook} % nice \every... patching
% restyle figures to make \everymath=\sansmath (float package)
\restylefloat{figure}
 \floatevery{figure}{\PushPreHook{math}{\sansmath}}
% undo the change to \everymath at the end of the figure (etoolbox)
 \apptocmd{\endfigure}{\PopPreHook{math}}{}{}

\tikzset{font=\sffamily\small\sansmath}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

Main text is in Times. Works without a problem.

\begin{equation}
    \Delta\Omega(t)
\end{equation}

My problem is in the figures, which I usually typeset using Ti\emph{k}z

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0, 0) {KPMath-Sans Equation: $\Delta\Omega(t)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Captions are in Helvetica. $\Delta\Omega(t)$}
\end{figure}

I found that I can get a fix if I manually put a {\textbackslash}mathrm around all of my capital Greek letters, but I would like to find a way for this to automatically be done.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] at (0, 0) {{\textbackslash}symsfup: $\symsfup{\Delta\Omega}(t)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{I can fix with {\textbackslash}symsfup... $\symsfup{\Delta\Omega}(t)$}
\end{figure}

While {\textbackslash}mathrm does not allow {\textbackslash}Delta{\textbackslash}Omega with this configuration,
\(\mathrm{\increment\mupOmega}\) works.
```

[image: Text sample]

I’m pretty suspicious of the copied code you are using to set the captions to use `\sansmath`, since it’s giving me warnings that the command is invalid in math mode.

Comment: For your example, do you have an idea of why the fonts are different in Equation (1) and the inline text of your final paragraph? The final paragraph gives me an inline equation that resembles Helvetica. The font in the figure captions and tikz figures looks like Computer Modern Sans (is it KPMath Sans?).

Comment: I can use XeLaTeX, but I'm in the final editing stages using PDFLaTeX, and I have a bunch of other imports. If I can't find another solution, I may switch over to XeLaTeX, and change around the libraries that I'm using to make sure everything still works in XeLaTeX.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler One of the `\sansmath` is bleeding through and setting the math version to `sans`. I think the culprit is the uncdocumented use of `\floatevery`, which I did not change or attempt to debug. What you possibly want is to wrap your floats in `\begingroup\sffamily\sansmath` ... `\endgroup`. Another very ugly hack would be to switch back with `\mathnormal`.